# Отображение камеры в сцене Unity

Tags: unity3d

Почему то перестали отображаться линии, как на левом скрине.
Как их вернуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В редакторе в окне "Scene" включите режим "Gizmos".